# Twitter bootstrap button group tweak

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a button group, with three buttons, I want the buttons to be equally sized and take the screen width (since its a mobile app), I tried to add span4 but it didn't work. What's the approach here?

Comment: What exactly didn't work? Adding `spanX` to any element changes its width, so it should work somehow. I think grouped buttons override the gutter margins, so it may be easier to set the width manually without spans.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://plnkr.co/edit/oZ8Gy2rmG9qxU2UeizVM

see working example.  basically 100/3 should be the width of each button inside the container div

```
<div class="container">

     <ul class="list-inline">
       <li><button class="btn btn-default">Button</button></li>
       <li><button class="btn btn-default">Button</button></li>
       <li><button class="btn btn-default">Button</button></li>

     </ul>

   </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add CSS class

```
btn-group-justified
```

to the button group.